# Oracle sql script with parameters - difference between # and $

Tags: sql, oracle, flyway, sql-scripts

I have the following CREATE TABLE ${schema_name}.TABLE and CREATE TABLE #[schema_name].TABLE.
I have some migrations to do with Flyway and the ones with # do not work.
What is the difference between these two? (given that the ones with # are from working code)

Comment: I don't know Flyway, but I presume that's something created by it because none of e.g. `create table $scott.test (id number);` or `create table #scott.test (id number);` represents valid syntax (as far as Oracle is concerned). Both raise `ORA-00911: invalid character`, pointing to `$` or `#`.

Comment: In the build.gradle I have a flyway { placeholders = ['schema_name': somename]}. 
ORA-00911: invalid character is raised only when using # construction.

Answer (score 0):

There was a special configuration made in flyway properties file:

flyway.placeholderPrefix=#[

flyway.placeholderSuffix=]